# Matrix Determinant question

Tags: matrices, determinant

> $A$ is a $4 \times4$ matrix, $A$ has a typical element $a_{ij}$ s.t.
>   $|A|=4$. Now consider a matrix $B$ with every $b_{ij}=-2\cdot a_{ij}$, then
>   $|B|$ is ?

If we take out $-2$ from each row of $B$ we get $(-2)\cdot(-2)\cdot(-2)\cdot(-2)= 16$.

Therefore, $|B|=16\cdot 4=64$ ? Is this right?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. In general:

If $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, then for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$:

$$|\lambda A| = \lambda^n|A|$$

In this case:

$$|B| =|-2A| = (-2)^4|A| = 16|A| = 64$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is correct. In general if $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix with coefficients in $K$ then $|\lambda A|=\lambda^n |A|$ for any $\lambda\in K$.